# 電卓プログラムの機能拡張(log、三角関数、pi、etc)をしたいのですがどうしたらよいでしょうか

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

jupyterのpythonで下記のプログラムで`self.value=eval(self.entry.get().replace)`と記号の置き換えをしているのですが演算子以外のものをどう書けばいいのかわかりません。どなたかおしえていただきたいです。

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("400x300")
        self.master.title('計算機')
        
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master, justify="right")

        self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu_bar)

        self.create_widgets()

    def input(self, action):
        self.entry.insert(tk.END, action)

    def clear_all(self):
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def clear_one(self):
        txt = self.entry.get()
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry.insert(0, txt[:-1])

    def equals(self):
        self.value = eval(self.entry.get().replace('÷', '/').replace('x', '*').replace('%', '/100').replace('^','**').replace('√','**0.5').replace(''))
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry.insert(0, self.value)

    def create_widgets(self):
        file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_bar)
        file_menu.add_command(label='閉じる', command=self.master.quit)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label='メニュー', menu=file_menu)

        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=3)
        self.entry.focus_set()
 
        tk.Button(self.master, text='7', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(7)).grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='8', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(8)).grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='9', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(9)).grid(row=2, column=2)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='4', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(4)).grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='5', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(5)).grid(row=3, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='6', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(6)).grid(row=3, column=2)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='1', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(1)).grid(row=4, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='2', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(2)).grid(row=4, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='3', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input(3)).grid(row=4, column=2)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='0', width=9,
                  command=lambda: self.input(0)).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='.', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input('.')).grid(row=5, column=2)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='=', width=4,
                  command=self.equals).grid(row=5, column=3)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='x', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input('x')).grid(row=2, column=3)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='-', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input('-')).grid(row=3, column=3)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='+', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input('+')).grid(row=4, column=3)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='AC', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.clear_all()).grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='C', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.clear_one()).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='%', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input('%')).grid(row=1, column=2)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='÷', width=4,
                  command=lambda: self.input('÷')).grid(row=1, column=3)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='^',width=4,
                 command=lambda: self.input('^')).grid(row=1,column=4)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='√',width=4,
                 command=lambda: self.input('√')).grid(row=2,column=4)
              
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: 計算式を1行で処理しようとするから詰まってしまうのでは？ 安価な電卓のように、ボタンを押すごとに処理したほうが簡単でしょう。[python 3 calculator with tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52434544/9014308), [Python GUI tkinter Scientific Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44357846/9014308)

Comment: あるいは、この記事 [関数電卓 (Python 版)](http://www.shido.info/py/python_calc.html) のようにコマンドライン入力で動作する電卓プログラムを使い、その入力書式に準拠した計算式文字列をtkinterで組み立ててから、呼び出して結果を表示する。といったことも考えられます。

Comment: こちら [shekhar8897/Scientific-calculator](https://github.com/shekhar8897/Scientific-calculator) がPython2.x系ですが各種関数を使えるプログラムです。`2to3.py`を通してPython3.x系用に変換したら動作しました。プログラムの構造は大きく違うようなのですがね。