# 関数電卓から手入力で関数グラフを描写したい

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

jupyterのpythonで関数電卓のプログラムを組んだのですが、その電卓から手入力をしてグラフを描写したいです。

matplotを使用して電卓プログラムの後に関数をグラフに描写するプログラムを書いた方が良いのでしょうか？下記のプログラムで関数プログラムを書いてから関数のプログラムを書いたら実行を終了したら表示されました。

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry('500x700')

        self.master.title('計算機')

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master, justify="right")

        self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu_bar)

        self.create_widgets()


    def input(self, action):
        self.entry.insert(tk.END, action)

    def clear_all(self):
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def clear_one(self):
        txt = self.entry.get()
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry.insert(0, txt[:-1])

    def entered_value(self):
        return eval(self.entry.get().replace('÷', '/').replace('x', '*').replace('%', '/100').replace('^','**').replace('√','**0.5').replace('e','math.e'))

    def equals(self):
        self.value = self.entered_value()
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry.insert(0, self.value)

    def unary(self, function):
        self.value = function(self.entered_value())
        self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry.insert(0, self.value)

    def create_widgets(self):
        file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_bar)
        file_menu.add_command(label='閉じる', command=self.master.quit)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label='メニュー', menu=file_menu)

        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=3)
        self.entry.focus_set()

        tk.Button(self.master, text='7', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(7)).grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='8', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(8)).grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='9', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(9)).grid(row=2, column=2)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='4', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(4)).grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='5', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(5)).grid(row=3, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='6', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(6)).grid(row=3, column=2)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='1', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(1)).grid(row=4, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='2', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(2)).grid(row=4, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='3', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input(3)).grid(row=4, column=2)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='0', width=12,
                  command=lambda: self.input(0)).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='.', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input('.')).grid(row=5, column=2)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='=', width=7,
                  command=self.equals).grid(row=5, column=3)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='x', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input('x')).grid(row=2, column=3)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='-', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input('-')).grid(row=3, column=3)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='+', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input('+')).grid(row=4, column=3)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='AC', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.clear_all()).grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='C', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.clear_one()).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='%', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input('%')).grid(row=1, column=2)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='÷', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.input('÷')).grid(row=1, column=3)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='sin', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.unary(math.sin)).grid(row=1, column=5)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='cos', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.unary(math.cos)).grid(row=2, column=5)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='tan', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.unary(math.tan)).grid(row=3, column=5)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='log', width=7,
                  command=lambda: self.unary(math.log10)).grid(row=4, column=5)

        tk.Button(self.master, text='^', width=7,
                 command=lambda: self.input('^')).grid(row=1,column=4)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='π', width=7,
                 command=lambda: self.input(math.pi)).grid(row=2,column=4)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='√', width=7,
                 command=lambda: self.input('√')).grid(row=3,column=4)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='e', width=7,
                 command=lambda: self.input('e')).grid(row=4,column=4)
        tk.Button(self.master, text='!', width=7,
                 command=lambda: self.unary(math.factorial)).grid(row=5,column=4)

fig = plt.figure()
X = fig.add_subplot(221)

X.plot()

plt.show()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: たとえば「＝」ボタンを押したらそのときの数式に応じてグラフを変化させたいということでしょうか？グラフの描画部分（`fig = plt.figure()`以降）を`Application`の外に書いてしまったために、実行を終了してからでないとグラフが表示されないのだと思います。

Comment: こちらの質問[電卓プログラムの機能拡張...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69931/26370)と同様の課題から派生したのでしょうか、ソースコードの大部分が類似しています。グラフを描きたいという件だとこれら [bkthomps/GraphingCalculator](https://github.com/bkthomps/GraphingCalculator), [yasasvi0510/Graphing-Calculator](https://github.com/yasasvi0510/Graphing-Calculator), [tanishq1g/Interpretor-Graph-Plotter](https://github.com/tanishq1g/Interpretor-Graph-Plotter) が参考になるかも。後ろ2つはPython2.x系なのでPython3.x系で使うには変換が必要ですが。他にkivyを使うらしい [TomJamesGray/calculator_proj](https://github.com/TomJamesGray/calculator_proj) もあるようです。

Comment: sei0o様、コメントありがとうございます。=を押したら数式に応じたグラフを作りたいと思っています。fig = plt.figure()をApplication(master=root)以降に記述するということでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: kunif様、コメントありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂いています。